# Why HashSet doesn't build all the methods of the Set interface

Tags: java, set, hashset

I knew from my java courses that when i implement an interface i have to build all the methods that exist in that interface.But when i took a look of the HashSet class i observed that it didnt build all the methods of the Set interface.Why?

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't "build all the methods?" Every method defined in `Set` is implemented by `HashSet`, or by a superclass of it.

Comment: Which methods do you think are not implemented?

Comment: A (concrete) class would not compile if it didn't implement all required methods.

Comment: Ok thanks i didnt noice that the set interface is subinterface of Collection and Iterable interfaces which their methods were implemented by superclasses of HashSet class.Thanks for the response

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the `HashSet` class declaration, you can see that besides implementing `Set`, `Cloneable`, and `Serializable`, it extends the `AbstractSet` class, which itself extends `AbstractCollection`.

For example, the two `toArray()` overloads are implemented in the `AbstractCollection` class. So are the `addAll()`, `containsAll()`, `retainAll()`, and `removeAll()` methods. Moreover, `removeAll()` is overridden in `AbstractSet`.

The `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods, which are defined in `Object`, are overridden in `AbstractSet`.

Hope this helps...

Jeff

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the superclass, AbstractSet.  From the java docs: "This class provides a skeletal implementation of the Set interface to minimize the effort required to implement this interface."  HashSet extends AbstractSet so anything not implemented in AbstractSet is implemented in HashSet.

Answer (score 0):

`HashSet` implements all the methods of the `Set` interface. Not all of them appear directly in the `HashSet` code because some (e.g. `removeAll`) are inherited from `AbstractSet`, and others (e.g. `toArray`) are inherited from `AbstractCollection`. You can see all this in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html).

These abstract classes are extremely useful. If you extend `AbstractSet`, all you have to do is override `size`, `contains` and `iterator`, and you get correctly functioning versions of other methods (e.g. `containsAll`, `hashCode`, `toArray`, `stream`) for free. You may choose to override them anyway to make them more efficient.